# Fastest get file content function in c++ and detect binary or text auto

Tags: c++, binary, buffer, ifstream

Hello i am using this function to get files content in c++

```
        // Create buffer
        ostringstream Buffer;

        // Set handler
        ifstream Handler(Path, ios::in);

        // Get lines
        Buffer << Handler.rdbuf();

        // Return
        return Buffer.str();
```

But i have 2 problems with this function
1 - This function is very slow and when i compere it with `file_get_content` in php, php function is about **15x** faster

2 - For binrary i have to change this function and use `(ios::binary)` so there is no way that this function detect file is text or binary and i have to do this myself ...

now i need a function to get files content (fastest) function and can detect file is text or binary and use the true action ....

Comment: `ios::binary` will read ascii files just fine (it only bypasses translating newline characters to `\r\n` on the fly), so you can probably just use that regardless.

It'd be helpful if you provided your PHP code as well. I don't know PHP, but maybe someone can explain why it is faster and how to do the equivalent in C++.

Comment: Hi, you can try C file interface. It will be faster then streams. For detecting binary/text the simplest method would be to read few hundred bytes from file and check if contains \0 with memory operations.

Comment: Can you create this function for me?